# Group by first occurrence of each value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| id | user | action | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | start | 12/10/2022 |
| 2 | Jim | start | 12/10/2022 |
| 3 | Jim | end | 2/2/2022 |
| 4 | Linette | start | 8/18/2022 |
| 5 | Linette | start | 3/24/2022 |
| 6 | Linette | end | 8/27/2022 |
| 7 | Rachel | start | 2/7/2022 |
| 8 | Rachel | end | 1/4/2023 |
| 9 | James | start | 6/12/2022 |
| 10 | James | end | 5/14/2022 |
| 11 | James | start | 11/28/2022 |
| 12 | James | start | 8/9/2022 |
| 13 | James | end | 2/15/2022 |

For each user, there can be more than one start event, but only one end. Imagine that they sometimes need to start a book over again, but only finish it once.

What I want is to calculate the time difference between the *first* start and the end, so keep, for each user, the *first* occurrence of "start" and "end" in each group.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> (df.groupby(["user", "action"], sort=False)["timestamp"]
       .first()
       .droplevel("action")
       .diff().iloc[1::2])

user
James       29 days
Jim        311 days
Linette     -9 days
Rachel    -331 days
Name: timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

- for "timestamp" of each "user" & "action" pair, get the first occurences

  - this will effectively take the first start, and the (only) end
- then drop the carried over "action" level of groupers
- take the difference from ends and starts
- take every other value to get per-user difference

(sort=False ensures during groupby that start's don't get mixed up.)

Comment: Ah yes! I had tried `first()` but it returned only the first occurrence "start". But that's only because I had added it as a column matching the timestamp, not as a group to select the first occurrence from. Thanks!